# Why does download have a little x icon on left corner?

Tags: macos

I downloaded PostgreSQL from [here](http://postgresapp.com/). But when I look at Downloads folder, it looks different from other downloads. It has a small x icon on corner:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I deleted it and redownloaded again and no x, although the file size remains the same. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The little circled (x), on the icon, is to stop the download. While it shows the reported download size, nonetheless it appears the download hasn't competed yet, and or if the downloading has stopped then something may be wrong and why it hasn't completed.